# Checking if a dictionary contains a value in a list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a bunch of page objects in a collection.
Each page has some meta info.
Some of the pages have a meta called tag, which is a list of tags.

How can I select the pages that have a meta tag attribute and that tag contains a certain value?

I was thinking about something along:

```
articles = [p for p in pages
            and 'tags' in p.meta
            and tag in p.meta.tags]
```

(This code fails `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'tags'`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `p.meta` is a dictionary that contains a `'tags'` key, you would perform the lookup using `p.meta['tags']` or `p.meta.get('tags')`, not `p.meta.tags`.  So in the end your comprehension might look like this:

```
articles = [p for p in pages
            if 'tags' in p.meta
            and tag in p.meta['tags']]
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the first `and` to `if`, and use square brackets to access dict items.

```
articles = [p for p in pages
            if 'tags' in p.meta and tag in p.meta['tags']]
```

Alternatively, you could pretend an absent `tags` key is an empty list.

```
articles = [p for p in pages
            if tag in p.meta.get('tags', [])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tag` is not `None`, I would do this:

```
articles = [p for p in pages
            if tag in p.meta.get('tags')]
```